# Axes labels in plotly in R

Tags: r, graphics, plotly

Hi I the have following code in R plotly.
I want to provide axes ticks for e.g. `0:10` for X-axis and `seq(from=1000, to=4000, length.out=11)` for Y-axis. Can you please help me with this ?

```
set.seed(0)

#Sample matrix
bitmap<-matrix(rnorm(150000,mean=1:500),nrow = 300, ncol = 500)

plot_ly(z=bitmap) %>% add_heatmap()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for [`tickvals`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-xaxis-tickvals) and [`ticktext`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-xaxis-ticktext)?

```
library(plotly)
library(magrittr)
set.seed(0)

#Sample matrix
nrows <- 300
ncols <- 500
bitmap<-matrix(rnorm(150000 ,mean = 1:500),nrow = nrows, ncol = ncols)

plot_ly(z=bitmap) %>% 
  add_heatmap() %>% 
  layout(xaxis=list(tickvals = seq(from = 0, 
                                   to = ncols, 
                                   length.out = 10),
                    ticktext = c(0:9)),
         yaxis=list(tickvals = seq(from = 0,
                                   to = nrows,
                                   length.out = 11),
                    ticktext = seq(from = 1000, 
                                   to = 4000, 
                                   length.out = 11)
                    )
         )
```

[image]